# Mandatory While Loop Gives Local Variable Might Be Referenced Before Assignment

Tags: python, python-3.x

The issue I am having is that it should be impossible not break out of the while loop, AKA "matched_index" will always be defined, yet my IDE is throwing an "may be referenced before assignment" error. What is the Pythonic way to code this? The closest I found was [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39990133/while-loop-unboundlocalerror-local-variable-referenced-before-assignment), but I'm not sure how to code what kindall is suggesting.

Here is my code:

```
        another_list = [0] * len(my_list)
        if X in my_list:
            i = 0
            while i < len(my_list):
                if X == my_list[i]:
                    matched_index = i
                    break
                i += 1
            another_list[matched_index] = 0.2
```

Comment: The pythonic way would be to use a for-loop, but the issue still stands. A solution is to define your `matched_index` outside the loop body. Note, the loop body will not execute if `my_list` is empty, that's what the warning is about

Comment: Note, your IDE is giving you a warning, this isn't an error.

Comment: To your second comment, I realize it's a warning and not an error, but I'm just curious how to code better. The issue is that my_list cannot be empty, so I need to figure out how to fix the warning.

Comment: You can just ignore the warning. There is nothing to "fix".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just initialize `matched_index`, or move your assignment statement into the loop (so that you're not using another temporary variable to hold it).

While it might be true that, from a logical perspective, the code won't run into a scenario where `len(my_list) == 0`, the lexer can't *guarantee* it.

Comment: In which case, it may be fine to just leave the definition where it's at, so the code would fail fast if your assumption that the list is always non-empty doesn't hold...

Comment: The problem with initializing matched_index before the loop is that I'm not sure what I should set it to. I am "exploding" a slice in a pie plot, so if I set matched_index to 0 or something it would "explode" the wrong slice in a pie. Perhaps I need more if/else statements?

Comment: If you have a precondition that this value is set to something specific, then putting it inside the loop would probably be the better option.  This way, you're not chasing variables when the root cause is that your loop condition isn't valid.

Comment: That's the solution, doh!

Comment: But now it gives me an "unexpected type" error. I don't understand, 'i' will always be an integer, how is it an unexpected type?

Comment: @Robert That sounds like a different issue, though.